# copy results of a view query into azure sql

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create historic data for my company; previously i asked how to copy a table with a timestamp into the same mssql database. realistically, it dawned on me that what i really need to do is the following
1) log onto my local mssql box
2) run a query of a view (select * from view_whatever)
3) copy the results of the query and add a timestamp into another database, hosted using azure SQL

if i were doing this from the same database to another table, i'd something like this:

```
DECLARE @copyDate DATETIME2 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
INSERT INTO Hst_Opportunities
SELECT OppName, Oppvalue, @copyDate AS copyDate 
FROM dbo.opportunities
```

the from part is what im struggling with - how do i copy cross server and database when the source database is MSSQL and the target is Azure SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my test, it appears you could create a linked server on your local box and insert the data using four part name:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'SQLAZURE', @srvproduct=N'sqlazure', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'NAME.database.windows.net', @catalog=N'TestDb'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'SQLAZURE',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'USERNAME',@rmtpassword='Password'
GO
DECLARE @copyDate DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
INSERT INTO [SQLAZURE].[TestDb].[Schema].[Table]
SELECT TOP (10)
      [Column1]
      ,[Column2]
      ,@copyDate AS copyDate 
  FROM [Localdb].[Schema].[View];
```